# Meatamask eth_decrypt decrypt multiple message once

Tags: ethereum, web3js, metamask

My application is using Metamask to encrypt and decrypt user messages using [sigUtil.encrypt](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#encrypting) / [eth_decrypt](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#other-rpc-methods)

Whenever the application requires the user to decrypt a message it will present the user with a Metamask dialog asking them to allow the message to be decrypted.

Let's say the application needs to decrypt 200 messages all at once. The user will be required to confirm the dialog 200 times. Is there a way for the application to ask the user to decrypt all the messages with only one dialog?

If not, then is it possible to combine all the encrypted messages and then ask Metamask to decrypt that message?

[Example](https://jessgusclark.github.io/decrypt-error/build/) showing the issue. Encrypt multiple messages and then try to decrypt them all. It will show multiple dialogs.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way for the application to ask the user to decrypt all the messages with only one dialog?

There is not.

> If not, then is it possible to combine all the encrypted messages and then ask Metamask to decrypt that message?

I do not believe this is possible. Encrypted messages should be packed together before encryption.

Comment: That's unfortunate.. I have a use case where it is not possible to have messages packed together for encryption. In fact this can be normal / expected when using asymmetric encryption? 
The public key goes out to multiple users, and only the private key can decrypt. In my use case, I have a multiple users using public keys to encrypt messages at will, these can be milliseconds apart at times. It makes sense to not have to authorize each and every decryption in this case.

Comment: Ethereum wallets have not been build for your use case, as it is niche use case not related to most cryptocurrency use cases. To support the use case you need to build your own wallet.

Comment: It's only "niche" as the blockchain field is so new/fresh. And still there is no reason that MetaMask can't support this functionality. (what's the difference between 1 message and 100 messages?) You never know what you're decrypting, and it's for your own use anyway. And if malicious site, there is still no difference. And about Ethereum not being built for this. Why would I want a separate keychain/key when I already have an assymetric key that can do this? 
In fact it's wrong to state that eth wallets were not built for my usecase, and your reasoning is unsound. Ethereum is turing complete

Comment: It's got nothing to do with what "eth wallets were built for". They utilise an underlying technology called asymmetric keys. Metamask already decrypt 1 message which is in itself proof that Ethereum Wallets (or any asymmetric key for that matter), is used for encryption/decryption. Under the hood, Metamask uses nacl which by default decrypts multiple messages, so Metamask is in fact preventing this default functionality that comes out the box.

Comment: " so Metamask is in fact preventing this default functionality that comes out the box" This feature has not been asked for this functionality before you asked it, so effectively this is a feature request for MetaMask team and likely needs a custom JSON-RPC API.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your input/correspondence(and suggestions) Mikko.
Do you perhaps know where I can submit this feature request. I tried github issues, but the page redirects me to a community forum which is inaccessible.

Comment: Ah! I found it on my second attempt of looking. https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Thanks again.

Comment: Not that they would care, as a feature like this is niche, so you need to end up building your own wallet any case. MetaMask team mostly work where they can make money and this is not going to make any money for them.

Comment: Well, I don't know about money, but the user base will be in the hundreds of millions.